# Python: Why is `not not x` more than twice as fast as `bool(x)`

Tags: python, python-internals

Consider this:

```py
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit('x = 1; t = bool(x)')
0.08783805199999506
>>> timeit('x = 1; t = not not x')
0.018457599000015534
```

Now I know function calls typically give you an overhead, but also typically, the small common cases (such as this one) are optimized by compilers and interpreters.

So what's happening under the hood here?

Comment: This is an artifact of Python and the particular call. The same would not hold in many statically compiled languages (or rather, the reasoning would be more obvious). Two things. 1. What can `bool(..)` *accept*? How does this differ from the *not* operator? 2. Compare intrinsic operators vs 'a call'.

Comment: Look at the code generated for `t = bool(x)` and `t = not not x`.

Comment: This made me look into `bool` source code. This is behind the scenes https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/boolobject.c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> typically, the small common cases (such as this one) are optimized by compilers and interpreters

Maybe in an interpreter with a JIT, but the reference implementation of Python doesn't have one. It really is performing a hash lookup of the `bool` name in the current global namespace dict, not finding it, falling back to a hash lookup in the builtin namespace dict, finding the `bool` type, and executing `__new__` and `__init__`.

In contrast, `not not x` gets to skip all of that. It still needs to execute `x`'s convert-to-boolean hook, but `bool(x)` has to do that too. The things that `not not x` has to do that `bool(x)` doesn't are two negations and one operation of converting a bool to bool, but that's much more direct at C level (and there's a fast path for the bool-to-bool noop conversion).